# Events of Android AVD Emulator keyboard

Tags: android, android-keypad

How to get the key events of the AVD emulator keyboard in my application I want to move my Sprite i.e Character based on arrow keys in keyboard of android emulator ?

Say Per one click on arrow keys of android emulator I want to move my Sprite 1.0f distance

and on enter key I want to show some animation ...

how should I go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

    } else if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: What about the array keys which are there in android emulator ?? I want to move my sprite 1.0f distance per arrow key clicked

Comment: @user1201239 You can use KEYCODE_0, KEYCODE_1 instead of KEYCODE_ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Why Edit text i guess something should be related to public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  .. if i am not wrong  ? I want the event of the key pressed in android emulator for which i want to move my sprite that much

Comment: which keyEvent you want? e.g. (Home key ,back key)

Comment: I want the key events of the keys in android AVD emulator